# Создание обучающей выборки scikit-learn

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Добрый день!
Меня интересует, как, имея несколько наборов текстов (предположим, формата txt), использовать их в качестве обучающей выборки для программы классификации текстов на языке python, используя библиотеку scikit-learn.
Во всех примерах что я нашел, предлагают загружать обучающие выборки - и нет примера создания и использования своей.

Comment: О каком классификаторе идет речь? Вам нужно сохранять информацию о строках? Т.е. хотите ли вы знать какие слова в каких строках встречаются?

Comment: @maxu, у меня пока нет точного представления как будет лучше, поэтому я был бы рад любому варианту, лишь бы работа не стояла а месте.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у вас есть набор текстовых файлов и категория для каждого из них (для обучения модели)?

Comment: @maxu у меня есть набор текстовых файлов, а также отдельные выборки документов

Comment: Для обучения модели нужны входные данные (текстовые файлы в вашем случае) и результат (категория). В каком виде у вас результат (категория)?

Comment: @maxu те же файлы, рассортированные по папкам, соответствующие категориям

Comment: Вы можете привести пример полного пути одного из текстовых файлов, чтобы было понятно как извлечь категорию из пути?

Comment: @maxu 

O:/categories/cpp/article_2.txt

O:/categories/python/article_1.txt

Comment: Это реально исходники или вы просто такой пример привели? Я спрашиваю не из праздного любопытства - исходники нужно токенизировать по другому (как мне кажется)...

Comment: @maxu ну разве что раширение другое. А так по этому пути файлы.
Пути и названия не регламентированы, так что если вы считаете что лучше использовать что-то другое то пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы в данном случае попробовал следующее:

1. составить "dictionary" (словарь): `{'ful_path_file_1':'category', ...}`
2. попробовать обрезать комментарии и константы (например все строки-литералы). Задача не тривиальная т.к. в различных языках - разные способы комментирования (единичные и мультистрочные).
3. "токенизировать" оставшийся после очистки от комментов текст исходника, чтобы получился список слов/команд
4. выбрать наиболее популярные комманды для каждого файла и добавить их к общему списку списков - т.е. в результате у вас должен получиться список, каждым элементом которого, будет список отобранных слов/комманд соответствуещего исходного файла: `[['#include ...', 'printf(...)', ...], ['import ...', 'print(...)', ...]]`
5. "скормить" полученный список [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

В общем как-то так...

**UPDATE:**

пример для первого пункта:

```
In [5]: import re

In [6]: files = ['O:/categories/cpp/article_2.txt', 'O:/categories/python/article_1.txt']

In [7]: input_files = {f:re.search(r'\/categories\/([^\/]*)/', f).group(1) for f in files}

In [8]: print(input_files)
{'O:/categories/python/article_1.txt': 'python', 'O:/categories/cpp/article_2.txt': 'cpp'}
```

Comment: прошу прощения, можно с вами как-то связаться?
Я был бы очень рад если бы у меня была возможность задавать вам иногда вопросы по python и sklearn в частности

Comment: @AndrewGorshenin, извините, я свои контакты в сети не раздаю. А чем плох вариант со StackOverflow? Если не ответчают на ваш вопрос в русскоязычной версии, то задайте в английской - там вероятность получить качественный ответ гораздо больше (просто потому, что там количество отвечающих на вопросы на порядки больше)

Comment: хорошо, спасибо что ответили так быстро. Тогда сейчас создам вопрос